# Evaluate a list of values in a column against a combobox value most efficiently

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete duplicate values in a temporary list based on a value in a combobox. The code below loops through individual rows to check whether a value matches. It is slow.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Set ws = Sheets("TempList3")

On Error Resume Next

For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 2) <> Sheets("Sheet1").ComboBox2.Value Then
        ws.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
```

Is there a way to evaluate the entire column's values against the combobox's value once and then delete all rows on a worksheet. Or perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: try to include `application.screenupdating = false`

Comment: Yes, I've included that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a looping Find function, it deletes the row where the value was found and then it searches again and deletes the next row it finds until it can no longer find the Combo value on the sheet:

```
Sub find_cell()
Dim find_cell As Range

Set ws = Sheets("TempList3")

stop_loop = False

Do Until stop_loop = True
    Set find_cell = ws.Cells.Find(What:=Sheets("Sheet1").ComboBox2.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not find_cell Is Nothing Then
           ws.Rows(find_cell.Row).EntireRow.Delete
        Else
           stop_loop = True
        End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing how many rows you are talking about, I used 10 thousand for my example codes. here are two examples, try the both and see what works best for you.

You can run through the column and unionize the range found, then delete the rows, for example.

### [See here for example workbook](http://www.xlorate.com/excel-vba-loops.html#Add%20Range%20to%20Range)

```
Sub UnIonRng()
    Dim FrstRng As Range
    Dim UnIonRng As Range
    Dim c As Range, s As String

    s = Sheets("Sheet1").ComboBox2
    Set FrstRng = Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)

    For Each c In FrstRng.Cells
        If c = s Then
            If Not UnIonRng Is Nothing Then
                Set UnIonRng = Union(UnIonRng, c)    'adds to the range
                'MsgBox UnionRng.Address    'remove later

            Else
                Set UnIonRng = c
            End If
        End If
    Next c

    UnIonRng.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Or you can try to filter the column B and delete the rows that way:

```
Sub FilterDeleteRow()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LstRw As Long, Rng As Range, s As String, x

    Set ws = Sheets("TempList3")
    s = Sheets("Sheet1").ComboBox2

    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

    With ws
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        x = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("B:B"), s)
        If x > 0 Then
            Columns("B:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=s
            Set Rng = .Range("B2:B" & LstRw).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            Rng.EntireRow.Delete
            .AutoFilterMode = 0
        Else: MsgBox "Not Found"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I like and used the filter method. The only change I made was to say Criteria1:"<>"&s.

Comment: What would it look like if I wanted to filter on multiple columns based on multiple combo boxes? Thanks!

Comment: Practice with your macro recorder to get an idea on how that would look.